# While deploying ingress gateway, what does injectionTemplate: gateway mean?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar, istio-gateway

While deploying ingress gateway, what does `injectionTemplate: gateway`  mean?

It is mention here: https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/gateway/#deploying-a-gateway

```
  values:
    gateways:
      istio-ingressgateway:
        # Enable gateway injection
        injectionTemplate: gateway
```

Also, what is the different between sidecar  and gateway templates?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the official Istio docs:
https://istio.io/v1.12/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/#custom-templates-experimental

"Pods will, by default, use the sidecar injection template, which is automatically created. This can be overridden by the `inject.istio.io/templates` annotation. For example, to apply the default template and our customization, you can set `inject.istio.io/templates=sidecar,custom`. In addition to the sidecar, a `gateway` template is provided by default to support proxy injection into Gateway deployments."

It seems the `gateway` injection template is a "custom template", specifically configured for injecting the sidecar into gateway deployments.

The older ingress and egress deployments (v1.11.0 and earlier) didn't use sidecar injection by default (`injectionTemplate`: ""), but it seems the newest ingress gateway deployments are injecting the sidecar using the `gateway` template by default: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/istio-official/gateway

Istio recommends enabling Auto-injection for gateway deployments.
From https://istio.io/v1.12/docs/setup/additional-setup/gateway/#deploying-a-gateway:

"Using auto-injection for gateway deployments is recommended as it gives developers full control over the gateway deployment, while also simplifying operations. When a new upgrade is available, or a configuration has changed, gateway pods can be updated by simply restarting them. This makes the experience of operating a gateway deployment the same as operating sidecars."

Only problem is, I haven't got it to work using the `gateway` template. My ingressgateway pod never spins up and I keep getting the following error in the deployment logs:

```
  - type: ReplicaFailure
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-03-17T12:19:55Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-03-17T12:19:55Z'
      reason: FailedCreate
      message: >-
        admission webhook "namespace.sidecar-injector.istio.io" denied the
        request: failed to run injection template: could not parse configuration
        values: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string
```

Looks like it might be an upstream problem with how the `gateway` injection template is configured. I also don't know where to get a more detailed answer on what the difference is between the default `sidecar` template and the `gateway` template.

I am defaulting to the older ingress deployment without sidecar injection until things become clearer.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the custom template in helm as follows:

```yaml
sidecarInjectorWebhook
  templates:
    hello: |
      metadata:
        labels:
          hello: world
```